# How to you get hold of the user defined $tmp_path folder in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I want to create some files in my component and then delete them.  How to I got hold of the $tmp_path variable that was set by the user in the configuration.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$config =& JFactory::getConfig();

$tmp_path = $config->getValue('config.tmp_path');

The API documentation for Joomla! is pretty helpful:
[JFactory::getConfig](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/JFactory.html#getConfig)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [`sys_get_temp_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) function.

Please be aware that if you are running an older version of PHP (before 5.2.1) there are several comments on that page which explain how to create the function.

Answer (score 0):

### For Joomla 3 , 4 and later

```php
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$tmpPath = Factory::getConfig()->get('tmp_path');
```